# .htaccess URL rewrite help!

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am moving my WordPress setup to a new domain and I have all these links that points to different sections of the blog, I was wondering if .htaccess could help redirect those link http requests to the new domain.

let say my current domain is

```
http://testserv.url.com/asso/site
```

and within this site, I have links such as:

```
http://testserv.url.com/asso/site/?p=1198
```

then on my new domain, given that I backup and restore my WordPress setup from the current site exactly with the URL

```
http://newsite.url.com/site/
```

so when someone clicks on

```
http://testserv.url.com/asso/site/?p=1198
```

it would redirect them to

```
http://newsite.url.com/site/?p=1198
```

Is .htaccess capable of doing rewrites like this? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to [read this about moving a wordpress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) and [this about the redirect](http://userguide.expand2web.com/how-to-guide/backup-update-moving/301-redirecting-your-old-website-pages-to-your-new-wordpress-website/). Also here's [a plugin that does the redirect for you](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/)

Comment: No Problem. Good luck with the move.